# spotfire calculations in the same column

Tags: spotfire

I'm a beginner in spotfire and I wouldlike to insert a column that will calculate for each clients of my table the difference between the date of an operation and the previous date of operation.

In the example below, I describe what I expected in the "difference column"

**Example of what I Expect:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@user8797355- The below custom expression will give you the desired result.

```
Days([Date of Operation] - max([Date of Operation]) over (intersect(previous([Date of Operation]),[Client])))
```

*Note: The output is in days.*

Here is the test output:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are welcome. As this answer helped, Could you please accept it as answered?